# How can creation times be preserved while copying on Mac?

Tags: macos, copy, rsync

I want to copy files and folders on my macOS 11 while maintaining the "created" time attribute.

I have tried the following commands in Terminal:

```
cp -p
rsync -atX
ditto
```

They only preserve modification times. The destination has updated creation times.

Comment: maybe `cd` in the dest, and try `find . -exec sh -c 'touch -t $(stat -f "%SB" -t "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" "$1") "$1"' _ {} \;` after the files are copied.